# Weird odor in my living room and kitchen

Tags: repair, wood, cleaning, hardwood-floor

Ok y’all turning to you for some help.

I’ve just moved into a new place and there is a horrible horrible smell in the living room and the kitchen. It’s been days and it’s not going away...

So far I’ve aired out the rooms, put baking soda down on the wood floors, let it sit for almost 15-20 hours, vacuumed it up, swiffered the floors, bleached the floors, washed the floors, and even cleaned all the walls as well. No luck. I’ve even tried adding candles, natural smells, and even cologne.

Since my last effort of cleaning the smell is a tiny bit better but no luck again.

Ideas, tips, or hacks — thanks!

Comment: what was recently renovated ? new floors ?

Comment: as far as i know, i dont think anything was renovated.

Comment: Check the drain plumbing for problems. Empty traps, clogged vents, broken pipes, failed AAVs, terrible DIY plumbing by former persons,  etc. can lead to sewer gas in the house.

Comment: is this new place to you or recently build

Comment: Close doors and see if you can establish one room where the smell is strongest. If you can't find it, you may want to get an exterminator in to check for something having died inside a wall.  Mice generally dry out pretty quickly; larger corpses may need to be physically removed.

Comment: I thought *where is this smell coming from* questions were off topic. At least according to the [help/on-topic] page...

Comment: @matt, there's a bit of nuance to "things that there might be a hope of directing the questioner to a solution for" and things that really just rate a close vote with no comment because "we can't smell that". Dead animals and sewage gas are pretty common sources of "horrible, horrible smells" But there are of course people for whom following the written guidelines trumps having any sense of nuance. So far they must not have gotten here as there are no close votes... yet. But it's of course not very answerable as it stands, either.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I'm still learning the ropes here. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Was the smell there when you perviously checked out the place,like before you moved in?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "weird odor" questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not give us enough information to pinpoint the problem, let's list the possible sources and fixes.

**Starting with kitchen sink drain.**
It might be clogged (not draining well)
The p-trap installation is wrong and not working keeping the sewage gases back.

To investigate, close kitchen sink drain with a plug. Take a picture of under the cabinet showing the drain pipes.

**The gas oven has a leak**

It will smell like rotten eggs.
If you have gas oven close the valve and call service.

**Less possible**

A rodent has died in the walls and it is decomposing.

Other: Previous owner has used some construction glue that would emit gases for days.